# Выравние элементов таблицы bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть следующая таблица на Botstrap'e:

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">NAME</th>
      <th scope="col">SURNAME</th>
      <th scope="col">NOTE</th>
      <th scope="col">ACTIONS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>SERGEY</td>
      <td>PUSHKAREV</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
      <td style="">
        <button class="btn btn-success">SAVE</button><button class="btn btn-danger">REMOVE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы текст в первых четырех колонках всегда подстраивался под высоту ячейки и выравнивался по центру относительно вертикальной оси?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table td:not(:last-child) {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" border="1">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">NAME</th>
      <th scope="col">SURNAME</th>
      <th scope="col">NOTE</th>
      <th scope="col">ACTIONS</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>SERGEY</td>
      <td>PUSHKAREV</td>
      <td>NONE</td>
      <td style="">
        <button class="btn btn-success">SAVE</button><button class="btn btn-danger">REMOVE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Оно?